# Trying to find Upperbound!

Tags: linear-algebra, integral-inequality, positive-definite

Is there anyway to prove the following statement?

$$\int_{0}^{T}a^T(\theta)b(\theta)d\theta \le c_1^2 \Rightarrow 
\int_{0}^{T}a^T(\theta)Kb(\theta)d\theta \le c_2^2$$

where $a(t),b(t)\in \mathbb{R}^n$, $c_1,c_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ are constant, and $K \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is a constant positive definite matrix or even if it helps it can be supposed diagonal with different arrays!

Comment: Are $a,b \in \mathbb R^n$, or is it rather the case that $a:[0,t]\rightarrow \mathbb R^n$? Note that you can rewrite your statement as $\langle a,b\rangle \leq c_1^2 \Rightarrow \langle a, K b \rangle \leq c_2^2$, where $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$ denotes the $L^2((0,t),\mathbb R^n)$-inner product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to assume that you want to find a $c_2$ for any given $K$ and $c_1$ such that the inequality holds for arbitrary $a$ and $b.$

Such $c_2$ cannot be found for all $K$ and $c_1.$ For example take $n=2,$ $K=\hbox{Diag}(2,1)$ and $c_1=1.$ Then consider the constant functions $a(\theta)=(1,1)^T$ and $b_r(\theta)=(r,-r)^T.$ The integral on the left is $0$ but the integral on the right is $rt,$ which becomes arbitrarily large for $t>0$ and sufficiently large $r.$